# Use {globals = _G}, return lanes.lua:329: can't copy non-deep full userdata across lanes

Tags: lua, lua-lanes

Most solutions here use `lanes.gen("*",{globals = _G},func)`. When I run it, I get `can't copy non-deep full userdata across lanes`. Maybe this is because of `io.stderr, io.stdout, io.stdin` which are `file` type or `lanes.core.cancel_error` which is `userdata` type or `lanes.core timer_gateway`. How to use {globals = _G} or workaround? Is it a bug?

Comment: Why do you need to copy the whole globals table across lanes?

Comment: This relates to my question about calling c function. I thought that lanes would transfer global c function to new thread. I am learning lua-lanes. Using _G is easy for testing.